# Rx EventLoopScheduler threading issue

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The following program runs two schedules on EventLoopScheduler.

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<int, int> _dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    private static Dictionary<int, int> _dict2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();


    private static async Task Test()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var i in _dict)
            {
                _dict2[i.Key] = i.Value;
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();

        var rnd = new Random();

        scheduler.SchedulePeriodic(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
            () =>
            { 
                _dict[rnd.Next(0, 10000)] = rnd.Next(10000);
            });

        scheduler.ScheduleAsync((s,ct) => Test()); 

        System.Console.ReadLine();
        return;
}
```

As I know EventLoopScheduler should execute everything on a single thread. But I get an exception in line
foreach (var i in _dict) System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
How is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I .add a Dictionary(Key, Value) in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421155/why-cant-i-add-a-dictionarykey-value-in-a-foreach) It's about `Dictionary`, not `System.Reactive`.

Comment: It's my fault, I have posted inorrect example, I have updated code.

Comment: Your code uses multiple threads. It's because of the async calls, not Rx.

Comment: The reason is that EventLoopScheduler does not use a SynchronizationContext. It's looks like a bug.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f72de96-153c-4245-8ee1-b1de2cd630a3/continue-after-await-on-the-same-thread?forum=rx